# Send Email notification when build failed azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I want to send Email when my azure pipeline build failed.
Now the requirement is I want to send Email multiple to address which should set from environment address i.e to address and mail subject will be dynamic.And mail body will contains error log or error log will be as a attachment.

Thanks in Advance.